# Android Simple Timing Question

Tags: android, timing

I need to implement a millisecond-accurate timer for a small game. Which method would be the most appropriate for this? My current approach is to use System.currentTimeMillis(). It seems to work well enough, but maybe there's some pitfall I'm not aware of. What would be the standard approach to timing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your timer will only be as good as your system implements it. It simply won't get better than that.

Being a ex-professional game developer (and still do side projects) I would recommend against a millisecond-accuracy requirement. You probably don't need it.

Determine your clock accuracy with this program:

```
/*
C:\junk>javac TimerTest.java

C:\junk>java TimerTest
Your delay is : 16 millis

C:\junk>
*/
class TimerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long now = then;
            // this loop just spins until the time changes.
            // when it changes, we will see how accurate it is
        while((now = System.currentTimeMillis()) == then); // busy wait
        System.out.println("Your delay is : " + (now-then) + " millis");

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like so many things can affect the output of that program, such as a context switch. I think you're right about not putting too much pressure on `currentTimeMillis` accuracy.

Comment: @Matthew, you're absolutely right. Granted, when I run it many (hundreds) of times, I get a consistent 16 or 17, never varying. You make the exact point I'm trying to make: don't rely on the accuracy of `currentTimeMillis`.

Comment: It's interesting, but at the same time misleading. I might say to myself "I ran this hundreds of times and it was always 16 or 17" but that's just my system. A different system could have a completely different accuracy for this. Java's goal is "write once, run everywhere" but if you're not careful, it's "write once, fail everywhere" (this is true for --any-- language, even if Java does a better job of filtering out the gotchyas.

Comment: Note: on Android you're better off with System.nanoTime().  Not because of the nanosecond-level resolution, but because it's based on a monotonic clock.  The value from currentTimeMillis can jump forward or backward if the carrier pushes a time update, which could cause your game to hang for a bit if you're using this for delays.  (FWIW, I do get much finer-grained results on a device from the above test with nanoTime().)

Comment: @fadden I agree `System.nanoTime()` will have a higher accuracy. But I still wouldn't recommend using that. The point I'm trying to get across is a program that relies on the accuracy/precision of the clock is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @corsiKa - what do you recommend doing instead?  Any pointers appreciated.